# Get all matches with pure regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working in PHP and need to parse strings looking like this:

```
Rake (100) Pot (1000) Players (andy: 10, bob: 20, cindy: 70)
```

I need to get the rake, pot, and rake contribution per player with names. The number of players is variable. Order is irrelevant so long as I can match player name to rake contribution in a consistent way.

For example I'm looking to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Rake (100) Pot (1000) Players (andy: 10, bob: 20, cindy: 70)
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 1000
    [3] => andy
    [4] => 10
    [5] => bob
    [6] => 20
    [7] => cindy
    [8] => 70
)
```

I was able to come up with a regex which matches the string but it only returns the last player-rake contribution pair

```
^Rake \(([0-9]+)\) Pot \(([0-9]+)\) Players \((?:([a-z]*): ([0-9]*)(?:, )?)*\)$
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Rake (100) Pot (1000) Players (andy: 10, bob: 20, cindy: 70)
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 1000
    [3] => cindy
    [4] => 70
)
```

I've tried using preg_match_all and g modifiers but to no success. I know preg_match_all would be able to get me what I wanted if I ONLY wanted the player-rake contribution pairs but there is data before that I also require.

Obviously I can use explode and parse the data myself but before going down that route I need to know if/how this can be done with pure regex.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What proceeds "For example I'm looking to get something like this:"

Comment: It wont work  with `preg_match_all` or `g` because repeating `()*` capture group will only save the last occurence which is `cindy` `70` as expected

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Those were just ideas I had considered - how would I do this then?

Comment: Why you want to get `a`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh I'm sorry that should "andy", edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
(?:^Rake \(([0-9]+)\) Pot \(([0-9]+)\) Players \(|)(\w+):?\s*(\d+)(?=[^()]*\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/41)

`|` at the last of the first non-capturing group helps the regex engine to match the characters from the remaining string using the pattern which follows the non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following Regex to validate the input string:

```
^Rake \((?<Rake>\d+)\) Pot \((?<Pot>\d+)\) Players \(((?:\w*: \d*(?:, )?)+)\)$
```

And then just use the `explode()` function on the last capture group to split the players out:

```
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
$players = explode(', ', $matches[2]);
```